# how to use Threads for traversing the directory?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

i am very new in using threads. I have got a task to do and don't really how to begin. Hopefully you guys can give me some hints.

I have to write a program, which traverses the directory and reads the text from text-files. 
A Master-Thread has to start the traversing. For each found directory the Master-Thread has to start a new thread. At the end, I have to return the number of all directories.

I am not allowed to use the concurrent api. Which means, I am only allowed to use wait(), notify(), synchronized etc.
I am using DirectoryStream for traversing.

I don't really know how to program a Master-Thread which starts new Thread for each single directory which is found.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hints to get you started.

1. Get hold of a decent Java textbook and read the first chapter on threads, etc.  Or the relevant part of Oracle Java tutorial.
2. Learn how to create a Thread.
3. Learn how to start a Thread.
4. Learn how to make a Thread do something useful.  Read about the Runnable argument to the Thread constructor.
5. Learn how to "join" a Thread.
6. You will need to figure out how to update a central count of directories:

   - Learn about "synchronized"; i.e. synchronized blocks and synchronized methods.
   - Alternatively, read up on the `AtomicInteger` class.

---

Note that this is NOT a practical way to count directories.  If is highly inefficient and won't scale.  (But it is useful as a learning exercise ...)

Comment: thanks. What is a practical an inefficient way to count directories? You can just write some catch words, if it is required to write a long text. I will look them up.